# what is the difference between import './style.scss'; in main.ts and css.preprocessorOptions

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite

demo here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-qzqife?file=src/style.scss

style.scss

```
$color: red;
```

main.ts

```
import './style.scss';
```

when i use `$color` in  `<style lang="scss">` , got an error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [sass] Undefined variable.
  ╷
3 │   color: $color;
  │          ^^^^^^
  ╵
  src/components/HelloWorld.vue 3:10  root stylesheet
```

If I configure this, there will be no errors

```
css.preprocessorOptions.scss.additionalData
```

so, what is the difference between `import './style.scss';` in `main.ts` and `css.preprocessorOptions`

Answer (score 0):

`import './style.scss';` is used to import styles from a SASS/SCSS file into your TypeScript file, while `css.preprocessorOptions` is a configuration option for your build system that tells it how to handle SASS/SCSS files during the build process.

Comment: but I still don't understand why error occurred when `import './style.scss'`

Comment: You can fix it in two ways; add you're scss inside the shard config [link](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#css-preprocessoroptions) or you can import your scss inside ur style like this: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6o1but?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue%2Cvite.config.ts)